# Swagger-Codegen/Spring-MVC: Where are the mustache files filled?

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger

My question is in the title.. =)

Where are the mustache files filled?? I try to find which of the JAVA piece of code is replacing the mustache templates into the java files and I cannot find this.. Does anyone know where this is done??

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I found some problems with the `Date` type in Java when transforming from `date-time` to `Date`.. I found the solution, but I have to correct this after generating the stub server.. And I don't want to do this.. Therefore, I'd like to add a `if` condition on the type to add some information..

Answer (score 0):

The filling logic is done in [1] SpringMVCServerCodegen.java with lot of the code generation logic written in [2] JavaClientCodegen.java. Swagger-Codegen uses jmustache templates which are in [3] resources/JavaSpringMVC package.

[1] swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/SpringMVCServerCodegen.java

[2] swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/languages/JavaClientCodegen.java

[3] swagger-codegen/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/JavaSpringMVC

Comment: That's what I found.. But I still don't understand where, for example, they take the baseName and add it.. My problem is that I want to add something **if** the Date format is used.. Do you have an idea of what I should search?? Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect using date-formats. In your swagger spec if you specific "format": "date-time" it should generate the correct java code. Will that work for you or are you looking to do something even more customized?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't generate the correct java code.. =) There's a problem with the format.. For example, when you return a `Date` object, it will return it in the Unix-Time format.. And I'd like to have it in the RFC 3339 format.. I know how to overwrite the format, but to do this, I need to check if a `Date` type will be used and if yes, I need to add a line like this one `@JsonFormat(pattern="...")` before the parameter.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/1035 Can you use joda-time?

Comment: I've never used joda-time.. I think that's possible..

But I would really like to be able to add more tags in the `api.mustache` and process them in the code.. (see my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32720623/swagger-codegen-spring-mvc-add-new-tags-in-api-mustache)